# Vuejs, catch warnings in production mode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Our app use templates from magento and sometimes it trigger errors(e.g. wrong props or special chars).
These errors will be muted in production mode.

But we should to track it by TrackJs.
So, is it possible to catch warnings in production mode?

Warnings example:

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Vue is run in production mode,all errors are hidden bij design, this is not something that can be changed, expect by running the development version. The reason behind this is that inside production, you should ideally pre-compile all your templates using your build tool or custom backend.

In development, you can use an [`errorHandler`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler) and a [`warnHandler`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#warnHandler) inside the Vue config:

```js
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
    // handle error
    // `info` is a Vue-specific error info, e.g. which lifecycle hook
    // the error was found in. Only available in 2.2.0+
    console.log('Custom vue error handler: ', err, vm.name, info);
};
Vue.config.warnHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
    // handle error
    // `info` is a Vue-specific error info, e.g. which lifecycle hook
    // the error was found in. Only available in 2.2.0+
    console.log('Custom vue warn handler: ', err, vm.name, info);
};

// Prevent vue from spamming the console with "helpful" tips
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    name: 'main',
    template: '<div></div><div></div>',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    },
});
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

For template problem, Vue uses the warn handler, but for errors thrown from methods, it uses the errorhandler

Comment: According to the Vue docs, the warnHandler "only works during development and is ignored in production." https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#warnHandler

Comment: Thank you for explaining, but i know about it from official docs. The reason why I need to catch it on production - we use dynamic templates which builded by CMS (magento). Sometimes it fails mostly from wrong props data.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Any news about this topic? I have the same issue than @AlexandrVysotsky,
Props are passed as JSON object from a backend, and sometimes are incorrectly formatted and breaks the whole Vue component.
In development mode, we can trace them with warnHandler but in production mode it gets disabled. 
There is then no easy way to understand what make the component break due to silent warning.

Comment: @lbineau run development vue in production. Development vue is slower because it collects data internally to show good stack traces

Comment: Hi @lbineau, we recently migrated to SPA and fetch all data from API, so no problem with it anymore. As far as i remember last thing which we used to solve it, we use html encode on BE side and html decode on FE side to avoid such problems. E.g. <component :prop="<?= htmlencode(json_encode(data)) ?>"/>

Comment: are there any updates on the topic? I need to track network errors while loading components.